# Jquery live does not seem to work in nested calls

Tags: radio-button, jquery

I am encountering a problem of jquery live function not consistently working for me (or that what I think).

I have the same html form which is used for both adding new comment and editing an existing one; this form is propagated using a php code at the server side through a GET call. The two forms are displayed in two different tabs (tab1: adding a comment, tab2: listing the comments; tab3: edit a comment selected in tab2) based on the tab selection. The "Add comment" form appears as the main content of the tab1; however, the 'edit' form appears based on the selection of the comment that needs to be edit in tab2, so let assume that the "edit comment" form appears as tab3. The below code work perfectly for tab1 when the form is the main content of that tab; but it doesn't work consistently when it is the main content of tab3, which is showed based on which comment need to be edit in tab2.

```
  $("input.sample_radio").live('change',function(){
                            if ($(this).val() == 'no')
                                    $('#sample_table').hide();
                            else if ($(this).val() == 'yes')
                                    $('#sample_table').show();
                            return false;
                            });
```

If you can provide me with some thoughts, it would be appreciated. My observations were:

1. I used $("input[name='sample_radio']") but this didn't work for the form of tab3 because it always end up at the form of tab1
2. by using $("input.sample_radio") I assumed all the classes of type 'sample_radio' would work, but it not working either.
3. live is supposed to bind events to the new elements added to the DOM tree after jquery calls, but it seems this is not the case for me.

Thanks

---

Following the suggestion of Mark Schultheiss

> Look into .delegate() which was presented specifically to address this by allowing you to specify a context.

I managed to solve this issue by binding the event to the selected parents (tab1 and tab3) of the radio buttons and then filtering based on the selector which is here is the name of the radio button element and as shown below:

```
$('#tab1,#tab3').delegate('input[name="policy_radio"]','change',function(){
                            if ($(this).val() == 'no')
                                    $('.policy_table').hide();
                            else if ($(this).val() == 'yes')
                                    $('.policy_table').show();
                            return false;
                            });
```

Thanks for pointing me to this point.

Comment: You should note that `.live()` does not bind handlers to new elements. It binds *one* handler to the `document`. When an event bubbles up from an element to the `document`, jQuery will check to see if the element that received the event matches against any selectors it was given, like `input.sample_radio`. As such, anything that *prevents* event bubbling will prevent the `.live()` from working. This should be among the first things you check.

Comment: This deserves more than one +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using .live you have ran into one of it's challenges.  When you change the selection context you prevent it from working properly.

Look into .delegate() which was presented specifically to address this by allowing you to specify a context.

See this post for some notes on delegate from Brandon Aaron: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery

And see this nice one on context: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery

Comment: Mark - Could you explain what you mean when you say *"When you change the selection context..."*? I'm not understanding your meaning.

Comment: What he had done (based on description) is change the context of the .live when adding new item in another tab.  The original was bound to one tab, but the added elements were under another tab so the context of the bind did not pick up the new elements.  So the change allowed him to attach differently as the dynamic nature of his page no longer is relevent.

Comment: Dynamic dom change is very similar in XSLT mid process where the current "context" is vastly important yet a difficult concept to grasp for many developers as they are not accustomed to the "where am I in relation to now" which is what makes XSLT IMHO a powerful yet underutilized technology.